# Erro ao instalar módulo - egg_info

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde, estou usando o python 3 por meio do Anaconda. Preciso instalar o módulo pattern e estou tentando-o instalar por meio do comendo pip.

pip install pattern

Recebo o seguinte erro:

"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

O meu sistema operacional é WIN7 x64

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já tentou essa solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error (SOen)

Comment: O meu problema em específico é que o módulo em questão não tem compatibilidade com python 3.

Comment: Infelizmente se o módulo que você precisa instalar não é compatível com a versão de python que você está usando, a instalação não será possível.

Answer (score 0):

Esse pacote não está disponível para Python 3 e não é atualizado há 5 anos (ou seja, provavelmente foi abandonado.)

https://pypi.org/project/Pattern/#history